# Rule to manage Replies to a calendar invitation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, rules

In Outlook, is there any possibility to move the answers of an invitation to a folder ? I mean move the calendar answers and NOT move the simple messages with the same title.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Create a rule for moving invitation responses:

- Click *File > Info > Manage Rules and Alerts*
- In the Rules and Alerts dialog box, click `New Rule...`
- Select *Apply rule on messages I receive* and click *Next*
- Under *Step 1: Select condition(s)*, scroll down and select *uses the form name form*.
- Under *Step 2: Edit the rule description*, click on the link labeled *form name*. This opens the Choose Forms dialog box.
- In the drop-down menu at the top, select *Application Forms*. Click on
  *Accept Meeting Response* and click the *Add* button to add this form to the Selected Forms area, and click *Close*.
- Back in the Rules Wizard, verify that the rule description has changed and click *Next*
- Select *move it to the specified folder*
- In *Step 2: Edit the rule description box*, click on the link labeled *specified*
  to open the Rules and Alerts dialog box.
- Select an existing folder and click *OK*. To create a new folder, click *New*
  and give the folder a name, select it and click *OK* and then *Next*
- If you don't want to specify any exceptions to this rule, click *Next*
- Type a name for the new rule or keep the default name provided and click *Finish*
- Click *OK*

Comment: You can also refer to the thread below to move the messages with "Accepted" in the subject to a specific folder.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a2d8d02-88a7-435c-a3a4-34c564117619/replies-to-outlook-calendar-invitations?forum=outlook